# parsing Azure id using regex

Tags: regex

I have following id that I would need to parse so that I could use only the vm name of id but can't figure this out

```
/subscriptions/0000x0000x0000x000/resourceGroups/MyResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.HybridCompute/machines/MyVirtualMachine/extensions/MyAgent
```

I have tried following lines but I have not gotten it work

```
| parse kind=regex id with '/machines/' vmanme
| parse kind=regex id with * 'machines=' machines
| parse kind=regex id with "(.*?)[a-zA-Z]*=" machines @"
| parse kind=regex id with  with * "machines=" machines ',' *
| parse kind=regex flags = Ui  id with * "MACHINES=" machines ',' *
```

Best try I had with *| parse kind=regex id with '/machines/' vmanme* but then I outputted a bit too much: */MyVirtualMachine/extensions/MyAgen*t insted only outputting *MyVirtualMachine*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this syntax:

```
| parse kind=regex id with 'machines/' vmanme '/extensions'
```

Does it work for you?